# sharepoint workflow wait or pause and performance

Tags: workflow, performance

Using http://www.attunix.com/about/blog/2013/october/17/sharepoint-2010-daily-reminder-loop/ as a reference to create workflows for a task type list. I have workflows to send e-mails when there are new items, e-mails when tasks are updates, e-mails when tasks are completed, and reminder e-mails when the due date is 3 or 1 day away.

Until the task is completed there is a workflow that waits until 3 days before the due date and then waits until 1 day before the due date.

I can't find any articles on what kind of performance hits there will be with SharePoint 2010 using this approach.

The list will only have 2-5 items added a month so it's not a heavy use list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paused workflows are serialized into the database when they are inactive, this reduces any performance concerns. When it comes time for them to "wake up" the workflow timer job brings them back to life so to speak.

Based on your volume, you will be fine.